# Configuring Corporate Windows Error Reporting On Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Is there any good documentation out there explaining how to setup Corporate Error Reporting (CER) on Windows 7? I found some information in [Advanced Windows Debugging](http://advancedwindowsdebugging.com/) but the book targets Windows XP and things have changed quite a bit since then. I could not find any tutorials on the Internet/MSDN either.

To give a bit of background information, I work for a company with 25 employees and I would like to send crash reports to a local server so that I can analyze what causes our tools to crash. I think I need to know two things:

- Setting up a Corporate Error Reporting server.
- Setting up computer to send error reports to our Corporate Error Reporting server.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing and am unable to find any clear documentation. I found quite a bit on WER and CER -- but nothing on the actual software used on the server to collect CER data or how to set it up. I'm actively looking into this and hope to find an answer soon. Judging by the silence on this post I'm assuming this is still an issue for multiple people.

Comment: The only link I could find is [To obtain the Corporate Error Reporting tool, see the Microsoft Web site at](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=29517). I found that link on another MS site [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457179.aspx).

Comment: I think the latest version is in the current MDOP package

Comment: Link to "Advanced Windows Debugging" is now dead. Archive URL: https://web.archive.org/web/20120917154013/http://www.advancedwindowsdebugging.com:80/ . If there's an up-to-date live URL for the book, I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Corporate Error Reporting (CER) is part of Microsoft Desktop Error Monitoring (DEM) which is a part of the Microsoft Desktop Optimization Pack (MDOP). Or at least this is how it was -- things have changed (see below).

The best guide I've found on setting up what you're interested in (CER) is here:

[System Center Desktop Error Monitoring (DEM) Documentation Resources Download Page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27753)

> System Center Desktop Error Monitoring (DEM) provides a fast and easy
>   way for any organization to centralize and diagnose application and
>   system crashes and hangs.  Instead of sending error reports to
>   Microsoft, DEM uses Group Policy and Windows Error Reporting, which is
>   built into Windows, to send reports to a server you designate within
>   your organization for diagnosis.  Since DEM is agentless you don’t
>   have to install anything on your desktops or visit any machines to set
>   it up.

Source: [Overview of System Center Desktop Error Monitoring](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee532078.aspx)

**It turns out that all of the above is now out of date.** I'll leave it for reference, but I think that now you want to look at Microsoft System Center Operations Manager (SCOM) running Agentless Exception Management (AEM). Oye. You can find some information about SCOM here:

[Preparing your environment for System Center 2012 R2 Operations Manager](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn249696.aspx)